# Ajax PUT request receiving empty response

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have written a HttpCRUDServlet, which will perform the following tasks (so far).

- Respond to OPTIONS method with the appropriate CORS headers (`service()`),
- Parse and insert the data passed in a PUT request in the database (`doPut()`).

All the functionality seems to be working fine, except that the client receives empty response.

Here's the source:

```
package com.gamersdemokrasy.http;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.gamersdemokrasy.DAO;
import com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class HttpCRUDServlet
 */
public class HttpCRUDServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private String uri = null;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

/*
 * @see HttpServlet#doDelete(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
 */
@Override
protected void doDelete(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.doDelete(request, response);
}

/*
 * @see HttpServlet#doPut(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
 */
@Override
protected void doPut(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    JSONObject dataJson = getJsonData(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream())).readLine());

    response.getWriter().println("Hello");
    DAO dao = new DAO();
    try {
        if(dao.create(dataJson, uri)) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else if(dao.getException() instanceof MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.getWriter().println(dao.getException().getMessage());
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_CONFLICT);
            dao.getException().printStackTrace();
        } else if(dao.getException() instanceof Exception) {
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            response.getWriter().println(dao.getException().getMessage());
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            dao.getException().printStackTrace();
        }
    } finally {
        response.getWriter().flush();
        response.getWriter().close();
    }

}

/**
 * Converts a parameter string into a JSONObject
 * 
 * @param data
 * @return
 */
private JSONObject getJsonData(String data) {
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    String[] params = data.split("&");
    try {
        for(String param:params) {
            String tokens[] = param.split("=");
            json.accumulate(URLDecoder.decode(tokens[0].trim(),"utf-8"), URLDecoder.decode(tokens[1].trim(),"utf-8"));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return json;
}

/*
 * @see HttpServlet#service(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
 */
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String method = request.getMethod();
    uri = request.getRequestURI().replaceFirst(request.getContextPath(), "");
    while(uri.endsWith("/")) {
        uri = uri.substring(0, uri.length()-1);
    }
    System.out.println("Debug>> Request:"+method + " " + uri);
    System.out.println("Debug>> ContextPath:"+request.getContextPath());

    if(request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        // Set CORS headers
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
                "PUT,GET,POST,DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Allow", "PUT,GET,POST,DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "180");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-type");
    } else if(method.equals("PUT") || method.equals("GET")
            || method.equals("POST") || method.equals("DELETE")) {
        super.service(request, response);
    }
}

}
```

Here's the ajax code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/gamedem/user/',
        type: 'PUT',
        data: {
            id: 'dominick',
            nick: 'pr@da.n4m3s!s',
            phno: '9739097300',
            steam_id: 'lorddominique',
            games_played: 'cs1.6'
            //phno1: 9999999999
        },
        //contentType: 'text/plain',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function() {
            alert("Resource Created");
        }
    });
```

I'm using Firebug on iceweasel 3.5.16, and the response 409 Conflict (Expected). However, the response tab under the PUT request is empty.

Now, why is the response empty? I sure did write the error in `response.printWriter`, and flushed and closed it.

Comment: @thinksteep,@alex Just noticed the Chunked transfer encoding. Would this cause any problem? Here are the headers  `Server Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type text/plain
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Date Fri, 30 Mar 2012 20:24:25 GMT`

Answer (score 0):

When there is error, I don't think you will see anything in error. You will get corresponding error code. As per HTTP Spec:  Here is [link](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) for HTTP Spec.

> If a    new resource is created, the origin server MUST inform the
>   user agent    via the 201 (Created) response. If an existing resource
>   is modified,    either the 200 (OK) or 204 (No Content) response codes
>   SHOULD be sent    to indicate successful completion of the request. If
>   the resource    could not be created or modified with the Request-URI,
>   an appropriate    error response SHOULD be given that reflects the
>   nature of the    problem

Comment: I am already returning an error code. I could change the error code, that's not an issue. What I'm looking for is a way to pass a string along with the error code. Although the error 409 is returned indicating that it's a conflict, the error message (e.getMessage) could tell the client where the conflict is arizing. I thought request.getWriter().println(e.getMessage()) would work, but the response in firebug is empty.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) for `HttpServletResponse.setStatus`:

> The container clears the buffer and sets the Location header, preserving cookies and other headers.

Try calling `setStatus` before you write the status message to the response writer.

Comment: Tried that, no difference. FYI, I'm using Java EE 6. and the javadoc says `This method preserves any cookies and other response headers`. Unline Java EE 5, where buffers are cleared.